# Appium WinAppDriver find element by accessibility

Tags: appium, winappdriver

Using Apppium WinAppDriver to automate my Windows application tests.
All working fine, versions:

- Selenium 3.14.0
- Appium-python-client 2.0.0

My problem is that i have some resources which can not be located using
`find_element(By.NAME,"name")` because name is empty. I've tried to use accessibility id which should be automation id as presented by inpsect.exe.

But core selenium driver does not support it and i should use "appiumby".
Tried the following:

```
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import
driver.find_element(By=AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID,value="Button1").click()
```

But getting error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named "appium.webdriver.common.appiumby"
```

Also when testing directly in python interactive i can import "appium.webdriver.common", but not "appium.webdriver.common.appiumby".

Any ideas how to get it working ?

Also in the source code found this:
https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/b70422b67f5254523ed360e1d196df0df04feab4/appium/webdriver/common/appiumby.py
Is deprecated specific to WINDOWS_UI_AUTOMATION only ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the answer:

```
from appium import webdriver
driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Button1").click()
```

And Button1 value was taken from inspect.exe Automation id value of the locator.

Answer (score 0):

Appium and selenium versions are inconsistent.  The selenium version corresponding to Appium-python-client2.7.1 must be greater than 4.0, while mine is 4.1.